# How to use the variable from the python in rpy2?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

My simple program extracts the database from Python and store in the variable row.

```
cursor = con.cursor()       
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM traffic")

    #Retrieves data from SQL
    rows = cursor.fetchall()  

    for row in rows:
       row = list(row)
       a = row[1:]
       b = row[:-1]
       print(a)
       print(b)
```

Now that I am able to get the month and traffic in list a and b like [1000L]

```
['January']
[100L]
['February']
[10430L]
['March']
[1500L]
['April']
[100L]
['May']
[1200L]
['June']
[800L]
['July']
[8000L]
['August']
[100000L]
['September']
```

Now I want to plot, histogram and piechart out of it.
The row contains two coloumns: `MOnth` and `Traffic`. I want to convert this into the chart using Rpy2. How do I do it?  Here's my table:

```
month     | traffic |
+-----------+---------+
| January   |    1000 |
| February  |     100 |
| March     |   10430 |
| April     |    1500 |
| May       |     100 |
| June      |    1200 |
| July      |     800 |
| August    |    8000 |
| September |  100000 |
+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: What's "the chart" (tam ta daaaam)? Sounds scary.

Comment: I looked into some tutorials and found :
    from Python-space variables 
Tried, didn't work!
Simply, I tried 
r.x11()
r('plot(row)')

Comment: If plotting is all you want to do, you can do it all in Python (using matplotlib).

Comment: No, I want to do the complex things. I am in the learning phase so thus decided to do the small things first.

Comment: Month and Traffic are two coloum name. First, I extracted the data in row! I want to covert that row variable into R variable and covert into charts. Tried r('plot(row)'), didn't work!

Comment: Some more points: 1. we cant duplicate your example because we can't access your database so we can't see what 'row' really is. 2. Python objects don't have 'columns', so 'row' can't contain two columns. Maybe its a python dict? We don't know, we can't see it.

Comment: What's the structure of 'rows'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make two lists from your database. Something like:

```
cursor = con.cursor()       
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM traffic")

#Retrieves data from SQL
rows = cursor.fetchall()  

Month = list()
Traffic = list()

for row in rows:
    Month.append(row['Month'])          # guesswork - what does a row look like?
    Traffic.append(row['Traffic'])
```

Then, now you have two python lists, you can make a plot thus:

```
>>> r.plot(Month,Traffic)
rpy2.rinterface.NULL
```

You maybe want lines:

```
>>> r.plot(Month,Traffic,type="l")
rpy2.rinterface.NULL
```

You maybe want nice labels:

```
>>> r.plot(Month,Traffic,type="l",xlab="Month",ylab="Traffic")
```

Comment: It's statically. I know how to do this. I am stuck in the dyanmic one.  Extracting data from database using Python and printing charts of those extracted datas.

Comment: Huh? So the real question is "How do I read columns of a database into python lists?" Then ask that.

Comment: No, you want to plot them. And to plot them, you have to make python lists from the row objects you are iteratively getting from your database. And although we can *read* your code we can't run it without a database like yours.

Comment: Im getting this error: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str. I think the list method didn't convert the tuples(default) into list. I tried doing:
  for row in rows:
           row = list(row)
           a = row[1:]
           b = row[:-1]
           print(a)
           print(b)
Worked but r.plot(a, b) didn't work