# How to plot using data in database in Rpy2?

Tags: python, r, plot, rpy2

The data are stored in a database called "data" with two coloumns "month" and "traffic". The table looks like this:

```
+-----------+---------+
| month     | traffic |
+-----------+---------+
| January   |    1000 |
| February  |     100 |
| March     |   10430 |
| April     |    1500 |
| May       |     100 |
| June      |    1200 |
| July      |     800 |
| August    |    8000 |
| September |  100000 |
+-----------+---------+
```

Now I have extracted the data from the database using python. I want the to plot using those datas. Here's my code:

```
#usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb as mdb
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
r = robjects.r

def database():
    """Retrieves the data from the database"""

    #Database Connection
    con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'devil', 'data');

    with con:
        #Submit statements to SQL server
        cursor = con.cursor()       
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM traffic")

        #Retrieves data from SQL
        rows = cursor.fetchall()  
        for row in rows:
            row = list(row)
            x = row[1:]
            y = row[:-1]
            r.plot(x, y)


database()
```

I want to plot using the variable x and y. r.plot(x, y) is not working. This is the error:

```
 res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
```

How do I plot?

Comment: You forgot to to ask a question.

Comment: What is in `x` and `y`? Looks like either one of the the variables is a list of the same number...

Comment: x holds traffic and y holds month.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the variable from the python in rpy2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981810/how-to-use-the-variable-from-the-python-in-rpy2)

Comment: Part of the problem is that Month is a character variable.

Comment: Yea, month is a character or a string variable. Can I not plot the character and numeric variable in rpy2? How do I solve my problem?

Comment: Like @Spacedman said I believe the char or the string has to be converted into integer. Tried: [int(m) for m in month] to convert month into integer but got this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Comment: When you call r.plot(x,y), x and y have only one value in them (print them in python and you will see). You are doing, in R, plot(1000,"January"), and if you do that in R you get that ylim error, because it doesn't know what to do with "January" on the Y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the loop. Look at what 'rows' is. Its a list of tuples of the values of the rows of your database. Probably. Print it and show us what 'rows' is.

Then you just need to unwrap those tuples into lists x and y, map the months to integers or maybe ordered factors, and call r.plot(x,y).